# PHP FileInfo Extension php.ini override

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I'm making use of a GD Library on my application which requires me to modify my php.ini to work. I understand if I uncomment to `extension=fileinfo.so` the application will work as required, but my challenge is that I don't have access to my shared host server configurations. 
My question, Is there a way around using `ini_set('', '')`

Thanks ahead

Comment: maybe you can put an php.ini file in documentroot dir or use .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting has disabled **ini_set()** function for security reason
if the hosting provider turn on **ini_set()** to you, you can have full access to php variable control, which the hosting provider don't want

for your purpose, you can do it through **.htaccess** file within your application root folder

two directives are permitted using .htaccess

```
php_flag <boolean-flag-name> on|off
php_value <flag-name> <flag-value>
```

php_flag should be used for on/off values

For example, the following .htaccess file will disable globals, set the maximum file upload size to 20MB, and allow PHP scripts to run for 10 minutes (600 seconds):

```
php_flag register_globals off
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value max_execution_time 600
```

You can also use  ini_set function. in php scripts  which  allows you to change a setting within your application at runtime. The function accepts two arguments:

ini_set(flag-name, flag-value),

**Example**

```
<?php
ini_set('register_globals', 0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
?>
```

We can query the php interpreter before changing these value to query, we can use **ini_get()** method

**ini_get(flag-name)**
Returns the configuration value. I’d recommend checking your configuration change and taking appropriate action. Don’t assume ini_get() will always work.

**ini_get_all([extension])**
Returns all configuration values as an associative array. The optional extension parameter returns options specific to that extension, e.g. ‘allow_url_fopen’.

**get_cfg_var(flag-name)**
Returns the original configuration value from php.ini (not any overrides set in .htaccess or by ini_set).

**ini_restore(flag-name)**
Returns a configuration option to its original value.